# How to get this maven multi-project setup right (war + jars + static files)?

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, war, maven-assembly-plugin

We have a (until now) small project, which consists of 4 eclipse projects. The `main` project consists of all the needed libs and an Ant script.

Now we want to convert this project(s) to Maven, while keeping the project stucture.

How it works:

1. Ant script compiles all projects (without main) to `jar` files
2. Ant script copies all those `jar` files into the `lib` folder of the `main` project
3. Ant script copies some static files (html, css, js, etc.) from the modules into some corresponding folders of the `main` project
4. Ant generates a `war` archive of the `main` project

The (maybe) problem with Maven:

- All projects depend on `main` project

  - so *I think* it's not possible to use Maven's normal compiling behaviour

I read a bit about Maven's possibilities and it *looks like* the `assembly` plugin could solve the problem?! But I don't know how to get all that stuff working...

I thought of this project layout:

```
+ parent-pom (with packaging: pom)
  - main-war (packaging: war)
  - module1 (packaging: jar, depends on main-war)
  - module2 (packaging: jar, depends on main-war)
  - module3 (packaging: jar, depends on main-war and module1)
```

Now the `parent-pom` must have the `<build>` directive with the `assembly` plugin I think?

Please help me. Thank you :)

Comment: Maven is opinionated.  If you don't want to change the project structure, it's probably going to be a pain.

Comment: But Maven *can* compile projects and copy files, so this must be possible ;) But how?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the structure? What is so hard to simply add a supplemental module to a Maven build ?

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest to change the structure of your project which means having the following folder layout:

```
  +-- root (pom.xml packaging: pom)
       +--- module1 (packaging: jar: depends on: module-common)
       +--- module2 (packaging: jar: depends on: module-common)
       +--- module3 (packaging: jar: depends on: module1, module-common)
       +--- module-common (packaging: jar)
       +--- module-war (packaging: war, depends on: module1, module2, module3)
```

The mentioned dependency to the war module does not make sense, cause usually you have a module which depends on an other but not on a war mdoule. So to solve that problem the simplest solution is to introduce a separate module-common which should take the code which is common for all modules. The war module has folders for html, static files etc. with a layout like the following:

```
 .
 |-- pom.xml
 `-- src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- com
         |       `-- example
         |           `-- projects
         |               `-- SampleAction.java
         |-- resources
         |   `-- images
         |       `-- sampleimage.jpg
         `-- webapp
             |-- WEB-INF
             |   `-- web.xml
             |-- index.html
             `-- jsp
                 `-- websource.jsp
```

If you handle the things in a a structure like the above you don't need to use assembly plugin or what ever plugin to copy files etc. it will be handled by default. As a result you will get a war file which contains the things you need.

Comment: Hey. Thank you. That looks pretty nice! so the `war` project will not contain any java code? But how does it know where to find the Spring libs? via web.xml? Would be nice if that works!

Comment: If you have spring dependencies put those into your pom. The `war module` can contain Java code but it should not contain java code which other modules depend on.

Comment: So, for an **easy** move to Maven, we should take the option without any Java files in `war module`. Later we can split things a bit more better if it's necessary. And everything get's copied automatically when I compile the `pom package`? How does it know to use the `war module` as the main project?

Comment: What do you understand under a `main project`? All modules are built and produce artifacts?

Comment: Will I run `mvn package` on the parent `pom` project or on the `war` module? The question was more like: If I run `mvn package` on the parent `pom` project, how does maven know, that it should put all those `jar` files inside the `war` archive?